# Check if a text string contains special characters in excel

Tags: excel, return, special-characters

As the title already mentioned, I want to check if a certain text string contains any special characters.

Currently I have created a column with the characters which are allowed (ASCII range 32-122). And I would like a formula which returns 'ok', if the cell only contains characters which are allowed and 'not ok' if the cell contains any character that is not allowed.

However, Is this even possible without using a for loop? (thus without vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your list of valid characters is in `A1:A91` and that the first entry for which you wish to perform the test is in `B1`, enter this formula in `C1`:

`=IF(LEN(B1)=0,"",REPT("not ",SUMPRODUCT(0+(ISNUMBER(MATCH(MID(B1,ROW(INDEX(B:B,1):INDEX(B:B,LEN(B1))),1),$A$1:$A$91,0))))<>LEN(B1))&"ok")`

Copy down to give similar results for strings in `B2`, `B3`, etc.

We can in fact do without the use of an explicit list within the worksheet, viz:

`=IF(LEN(B1)=0,"",REPT("not ",SUMPRODUCT(0+(ABS(77-CODE(MID(B1,ROW(INDEX(B:B,1):INDEX(B:B,LEN(B1))),1)))>45)))&"ok")`

Regards

Comment: It seems the following in a cell returns `OK` with your second formula: `="aa" & CHAR(10) & "aa"`

Comment: Returns "not ok" for me using Excel 2010.

Comment: Hmm. I am using 2016. Your first formula worked. 2nd didn't. Out of town now for a few days. I will re-check on return.

Comment: You didn't have that as a text entry, I take it?

Comment: Correct.  Exactly as written: a formula.

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting!

Comment: Curious.  Now back, and have restarted computer and Excel, and I cannot reproduce the issue.  I cannot explain the behavior discrepancy.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser!

Comment: your first solution works best for me. Although it needs an explicit list, It does what it has to do. In contrast, the formula without the explicit lists works 'most of the time'... As my worksheet also contains Uniicode characters which aren't recognized and thus return 'ok' when they shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

With your string to check in A1:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))>=32)*(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<=132))=LEN(A1),"OK","Not OK")
```

**EDIT** If the character strings to be checked might include Unicode characters, then you must use the UNICODE function in place of the CODE function.  I believe this function became available in Excel 2013.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((UNICODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))>=32)*(UNICODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<=132))=LEN(A1),"OK","Not OK")
```

Comment: would you mind breaking down your formula to let me understand it?
Also is there a way to indicate which character is the problem? in a second cell e.g. (only the first character that creates the problem is enough, or even just the number of the character in the string e.g. the 'n'-th character. As this formula seems to work, however sometimes it generates a 'not ok' where I can't locate the source of the problem.

Comment: @Weathus `ROW(INDIRECT(...` returns an array of numbers which act as the start number for the `MID` function.  So we return an array of the letters in the string.  We then use the `CODE` function and test that the code returned is in the range 32-132.  I don't have time this morning to see about your other question, but I suspect it is possible without VBA.  Use the Formula Evaluation tool to examine the workings of the formula more in depth.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification. Looking in the formula evaluation tool helps a lot. However I still had a few questions: 1) why can't I replicate this formula by breaking it apart? only executing the row(indirect(... part does not return the array which is created according to the formula evaluation tool 2) how does the last part work? you are executing a sumproduct with only true and or false statements.

Comment: @Weathus With the `ROW(INDIRECT...` put cursor in formula bar and hit `F9` to see array.

Comment: I thought this solution worked fine until I noticed that a lot of the special characters I need to filter out aren't recognized by your function. E.g. ≥, β,... are all unicode characters and thus are not recognized. Therefore this solution doesn't work well for me...

Comment: @Weathus  If you need to check for Unicode characters also, merely replace the `CODE` function with the `UNICODE` function

Answer (score -2):

Use OR with FIND function and return with IF function