# recognizing special characters outside a certain ASCII range in excel does not always work

Tags: excel, range, ascii, special-characters

I recently asked a question ([Check if a text string contains special characters in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675402/check-if-a-text-string-contains-special-characters-in-excel/37676706?noredirect=1#comment62832149_37676706)) on how to check if cells contain ASCII codes outside a certain range.

Since, I use the following formula:

=IF(SUMPRODUCT((CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))>=32)*(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<=126))=LEN(A1),"OK","Not OK")

where I check if cell A1 contains any special characters outside the 32-126 ASCII range.

And I thought this was working fine. However I noticed that this formula doesn't pick up all special characters. E.g. ≥, β,... are not getting recognized. The formula returns 'ok' even when it shouldn't...

Does anybody now what causes this? for other special characters, this formula works fine.

Comment: You probably have some *Unicode* characters that the `CODE()` worksheet function is mis-handling.

Comment: As mentioned in your other string, you need to replace `CODE` with `UNICODE` in the function.  I believe the `UNICODE` function became available in Excel 2013.

Comment: unfortunately, I use excel 2010 (company provided, so I can not update this myself) I guess I am stuck using the formula with a predetermined list with allowed characters.

Answer (score 1):

The beta is a *UniCode* character.  I put part of your post in **C1**

In **D1**, I enter:

```
=CODE(MID(C$1,ROWS($1:1),1))
```

and in **E1**:

```
=CHAR(D1)
```

after copying down:

[image]

As you see, `CODE()` returns *ASCII 63* for the beta.